# jQuery - attach event handler for linkButton

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a user control. It contrains LinkButton. I want to attach an click event to the LinkButton using jquery.

```
<%@ Control AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Pager.ascx.cs" EnableViewState="true" Inherits="Web.Controls.Pager" Language="C#" ViewStateMode="Enabled" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        eval($('#LinkButtonFirst').attr('href')).bind('click', 
        function () {
            alert('fsfsf'); 
        });
    });
</script>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonFirst" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButtonFirst_Click" />
```

The first error I've encountered is `Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined`.
But the Master Page already  have link to jquery
`<script src="/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$('#<%=LinkButtonObj.ClientID%>').click(function() {
 alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function () {
    $('#<%= LinkButtonFirst.ClientID %>').bind('click', 
    function () {
        alert('fsfsf'); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `ClientID` Property of the `LinkButton`.
IDs of the controls in user controls are computed not as ODs of the controls on page.
So you should use the code:

```
<%@ Control AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Pager.ascx.cs" EnableViewState="true" Inherits="Web.Controls.Pager" Language="C#" ViewStateMode="Enabled" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         eval($('#<%= LinkButtonFirst.ClientID %>').attr('href')).bind('click',
          function () {
             alert('fsfsf');
          });
     });
</script>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonFirst" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButtonFirst_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.8.0  `.live` and `.bind` are deprecated. try using `.on` to attach any event.
This makes sure the event is attached when the element is available

```
$(function () {
    $('[id*=LinkButtonFirst]').on('click',function () {
        alert(' Link Button was Clicked !!'); 
    });
});
```